# Using LINQ to perform a left outer join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to build a list that contains all the objects from one list but updates a specific property if the object exists in another list.

Firstly I create a List of all the possible "Options". I then want to update the "Selected" property of any items in this list that also exist in another list of "Options" that I have created. I was hoping the code below would work but I'm getting the exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

```
        var query = from o in AllOptions
                    join so in SelectedOptions on o.Code equals so.Code into newOptions
                    from no in newOptions.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new Option
        {
            Name = o.Name,
            Description = o.Description,
            Code = o.Code,
            Applicable = o.Applicable,
            Selected = no.Selected
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the exception from the `no.Selected` statement in your projection, when `no` is null it will throw because you're dereferencing a null.

You can fix it by specifying a default value when `no` is null:

```
//default to false when no is null
Selected = (no == null) ? false : no.Selected
```

Comment: Hi DoctaJonez, You answered seconds before I put up my own answer. I'm deleting my own answer now. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, we had a fun little game of quick draw eh? :-)  I'm glad you got the problem sorted.